# Android Vine/Instagram style video recording

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am asking for some pointers or guidance on how to implement the video recording feature that vine and Instagram use on Android.

That is, when user tap and hold, the video start recording. When user release, the video recording pause, but when user tap and hold again, the video will continue recording until it reaches a limit of X second.

Thank you

Comment: Did you do it? Can you share your experience with it?

Comment: @tasomaniac no I pushed this feature to do later. I will share my experience when I worked it out. Thanks for reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received same task several days ago. I would like to share my thoughts with you, I think You could record several files (MediaRecorder.start() / MediaRecorder.stop() will produce several video files) and combine them in one. For combine process [MP4Parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) looks nice.

Hope it helped you ;)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I have successfully combined all videos together. But the problem is front video showing as 270 degree. back camera showing 90 degree. How to change all the videos in same rotaion

Comment: Nicolas, that approach is okay but far from best. What happens if you start/stop one after another in short time sequences? Android MediaRecorder has nasty delay times on various devices, so you can theoretically even record nothing at all, following tapping scenario. Also, relying on mp4parser is a bad idea, what guarantees you that it will merge your sequences into one? I've been seeing cases when mp4parser won't merge sequences that in total do not exceed 400ms. Can you control merging with mp4parser? Totally not. 
The best approach (imo) is combination of javaCV and ffmpeg.

Comment: Hi murali, can you please share how you have combined the videoes together.